# Is it possible to use different symbols instead of colours in one shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want to show 50 bird species on a map and give each species a different symbol (with a different colour) so they can be visually distinguished in the map.

Is this possible?

Comment: While technically possible (see @dassouki's answer), it may not be recommended.  Representing 50 symbols on a map (even with different colours) may make it very difficult to visualise and interpret.  I tend to use no more than 10 symbols in a map if possible.  Any more than that and the reader gets bogged down with information and they're constantly going back and forth between the legend and the map.  I suggest splitting the data into multiple maps if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but here's how you do it in QGIS

**What you need:**

- Bird point vector layer
- In that layer, you should have a unique field (row) that identifies those birds species categories

**Process:**

- Right click the layer, then click on `Properties`
- Click on the `Style` on the left
- In the `Style` (top of the window) drop down click on `Categorized`
- In the `Column` drop down, click on the bird species category field that you have identified
- In `Color map` specify the colors you need. You can change those later
- Click on `Classify` (bottom of the window)
- Now you see, that the colors are different for each category.
- You can change the color of any category by right clicking on it and picking the option you want
- You can double click the row to change the symbol